# Getting values after a specific character and stopping on other specific characters regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get values  after a specific charachter and stopping on other specific charchters. This is what I tried

```
$whois = 'Registrant Name: Domain Administrator Registrant Organization: Yahoo! Inc. Registrant Street: 701 First Avenue Registrant City: Sunnyvale';
$data = preg_match_all('/:\s(.*?)\s/', $whois, $data_whois);
var_dump($data_whois[1]);
```

The whois is for yahoo: http://whois.domaintools.com/yahoo.com

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
  1 => string 'Domain' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Yahoo!' (length=6)
  3 => string '701' (length=3)
  4 => string 'Sunnyvale' (length=9)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
  1 => string 'Domain Administrator' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Yahoo! Inc.' (length=6)
  3 => string '701 First Avenue' (length=3)
  4 => string 'Sunnyvale' (length=9)
```

But it's taking only the first word. I believe that is because `(.*?)\s` I also tried `(.*?\s.*?)\s`and it's taking the second word, but if the value doesn't have a second word is going to take the word `Registrant` so I kind of need to stop on Registrant but don't understand exactly how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a lazy quantifier `.*?` followed by a `\s` the match will stop at the first whitespace character.

A way to solve the problem is to use the fact that `.*?` must be followed by a space and the word "Registrant" or the end of the string:

```
/:\s(.*?)(?:\sRegistrant\b|\s*$)/
```

An other possible way is to use `preg_split`:

```
$str = 'Registrant Name: Domain Administrator Registrant Organization: Yahoo! Inc. Registrant Street: 701 First Avenue Registrant City: Sunnyvale';

$pattern = '~\s*\bRegistrant[^:]+:\s*~';
$result = preg_split($pattern, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your fields has exactly two words followed by `:` on the second word. If yes then you may try the below regex.

```
: \K.*?(?= \S+ \S+:|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fD2dE6/1)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$data = 'Registrant Name: Domain Administrator Registrant Organization: Yahoo! Inc. Registrant Street: 701 First Avenue Registrant City: Sunnyvale';
$regex =  '~: \K.*?(?= \S+ \S+:|$)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Domain Administrator
            [1] => Yahoo! Inc.
            [2] => 701 First Avenue
            [3] => Sunnyvale
        )

)
```